# Server Monitoring Tool via file transfer

Tags: monitoring, system-monitoring

I am trying to figure out a way to monitor many Windows servers with a monitoring tool like Nagios, Zabbix even PRTG. The challenge is that server are onboard vessels without a reliable internet connection with limited data quota and bandwidth. So what I am thinking, a core server of a monitoring tool at office and Windows server onboard with agents which create a file and send this file to core server via email.

My problem is that all monitoring tools I know needs TCP connection in order to communicate the agent with core server.

Do you know any solution or how to create a file with sensor/agent data and load from the core server?

Comment: How is this useful for monitoring? Monitoring is usually real-time or near real-time.

Comment: Put the monitoring server on the vessel. If something breaks, someone on the vessel is going to have to deal with it anyway.

Comment: @joeqwerty Its near real-time, with 5 mins delay it work for us.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'd like to have a classic monitoring to all server, at the end of the day I will deal with it.